# WPF combox and multiple checkboxes

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

In XAML how would you have in a list or grid on the left side a combo box and the right  side multiple check boxes in a straight line?

Let say I had a data structure like.

```
sudo:

// for combo
class Option
{
  int key {get;set;}
  string value{get;set;}
}

// for checkboxes
class Selection
{
  int key {get;set;}
  string value{get;set;}
  bool isSelected {get;set;}
}


class Item
{
  Item
  {
    selections = new List<Selection>();
    Options = new List<Option>();
  }
  List<Selection> selections {get;set;}
  List<Option> Options{get;set;}      
}
```

Now this would be the item source.

```
List<Item> x = new List<Item>();

Item i = new Item();
i.Selections.add(blah); 25 selections
i.Options.add(blah);  3 checkboxes
x.add(i) 50 combination's. 

control.itemsource = x;
```

What would the XAML look like.  I am stuck as I quite dont get it.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <!-- This is your combobox -->
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="False">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Options}" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding value}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>

                <!-- This is your line of checkboxes -->
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Selections}" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isSelected}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Hello Monti thank  you very much.  I haven't tried it yet, but it gives me a good starting place!  Much appreciated.